# Can't type 'a' symbol in terminal

Tags: terminal, bash

I got into a strange behaviour of my terminal. Both iTerm and basic terminal on my OS X don't work. I can only type 'A' instead of 'a', but not the 'a' letter. If I try `bash --noediting` then I can type 'a' but it's very uncomfortable to use. I checked my `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile` and did't find anything that seemed strange for me. Could anyone help me? 
Any feedback appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most likely you've somehow introduced a readline binding for <kbd>a</kbd>.

As a first step, try this: (The grep argument is `$"a"`, but you can't type that :) )

```
bind -p | grep $'"\x61"'
```

It should print this:

```
"a": self-insert
```

If it does, then my guess is wrong, and you'll need to look elsewhere. If it doesn't, then you need to fix it, which you can do like this:

```
bind $'"\x61"':self-insert
```

Now you need to find where in your bash start-up files the incorrect `bind` command is. I'd start by grepping for `bind`. It may well be in a file sourced from one of those files. Good luck.

You should also check the file `~/.inputrc` which is used by the readline library to initialize it's bindings.

Comment: Well, after `bind $'"\x61"':self-insert` I can type 'a'. But I can't find anything with `bind`  in bash-startup files. I also grepped sources files, but there were no `bind` command. There was a shell script sourced in `~/.bash_profile` which didn't have `bind` command either, but even if I comment that line in `~\.bash_profile` it causes no result. What else should I try to check?

Comment: Did you check .inputrc? Do you have that file?

Comment: Yes, I did. There is nothing strange in that file.

Comment: @VladShablinsky: No line starting with `"a` ? If you rename `.inputrc` as `.inputrc.bak`, does the problem go away?

Comment: Thanks! That solved my problem. After renaming everything works fine. It was an alias in my .inputrc. I deleted it and it the problem disappeared. If only I had known that it could cause such a problem...

Comment: I had somehow piped a git commit into my inputrc!!! WTF! no idea how that happened, but thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

If the letter `a` has been mapped to one of the control characters, you can get some funny effects.  Try `stty -a`, except that you'll probably need to type:

- `s`, `t`, `t`, `y`, , `-`, <kbd>Control-V</kbd>, `a`

to get the `-a` to the command.  This should show you something like:

```
speed 9600 baud; 65 rows; 135 columns;
lflags: icanon isig iexten echo echoe -echok echoke -echonl echoctl
    -echoprt -altwerase -noflsh -tostop -flusho pendin -nokerninfo
    -extproc
iflags: -istrip icrnl -inlcr -igncr ixon -ixoff ixany imaxbel iutf8
    -ignbrk brkint -inpck -ignpar -parmrk
oflags: opost onlcr -oxtabs -onocr -onlret
cflags: cread cs8 -parenb -parodd hupcl -clocal -cstopb -crtscts -dsrflow
    -dtrflow -mdmbuf
cchars: discard = ^O; dsusp = ^Y; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
    eol2 = <undef>; erase = ^?; intr = ^C; kill = ^X; lnext = ^V;
    min = 1; quit = ^\; reprint = ^R; start = ^Q; status = ^T;
    stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; time = 0; werase = ^W;
```

except that if my suspicion is correct, one of the `cchars` values is `a`.

Comment: Doesn't work for me.
`cchars: discard = ^O; dsusp = ^Y; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
 eol2 = <undef>; erase = ^?; intr = ^C; kill = ^U; lnext = ^V;
 min = 1; quit = ^\; reprint = ^R; start = ^Q; status = ^T;
 stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; time = 0; werase = ^W;`